# Unable to get the data from Ajax html form to flask template python once button was clicked

Tags: python, html, ajax, api, flask

I am new to Flask,HTML.Kindly please help me.
I am unable to get the  parameter values from HTML form(index1.html)
My HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@@</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type=text/javascript> $(function() { $("#mybutton").click(function (event) { $.getJSON('/add_text', { },
    function(data) { }); return false; }); }); </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form  action="/add_text" method="POST">
         <h1 style="color:green;">CALCUATOR</h1><br><br>
         <label for="textv">First_No:</label><br>
         <input type="number" name="textv" id="textv" value=""><br>
         <label for="text">Second_No:</label><br>
         <p></p><input type="number" name="text" id="text" ><br><br></p>
         Result:<span id="result"></span><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id = "mybutton" value = "Addition" />
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

My Flask tempalte.py file is

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request,redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index1.html')

@app.route('/add_text',methods=["POST", "GET"])
#print("hi")
def Addtext():
    print("hi")
    print(request.method == "POST")
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("hello")   
        text_value = request.form.get('textv')
        text_value1 = request.form.get("text")
        #add=request.form["addition"]
        print("hi")
        print(text_value)
        print("hello")
        #text_value=int(text_value)
        #text_value1=int(text_value1)
        #print(text_value+text_value1)
        print('In SomeFunction hello $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$4')
    return 'NOTHONG'



if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Please kindly help me to fix the issue for getting the data from html form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have currently only one event firing on the button click which is a GET request. Now I assume you want to to do the following:

- Input numbers
- click button send numbers to back end (POST)
- After button is clicked and calculation is complete get the result (GET)

You can implement events for both POST and GET behavior on the same click. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106977/how-to-do-post-and-get-request-same-button-jquery) for an example. There are many more.